# Extract excel row and get the corresponding word in another column

Tags: excel, matlab

I have prepared a excel sheet in which two columns are there. In first column English words are stored and in second column corresponding Marathi words are stored. I want to first search the English word in excel file and if word is available then get its corresponding Marathi word. Code in matlab...

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
%%// Replace this with your XLS filepath
FILE = 'list1.xls'; 

%%// Read raw data from xls file
[~,~, rawdata] = xlsread(FILE); 

%%// English word to be translated to marathi. Replace this with your
%%// english word
english_word = 'yes';

%%// Compare the first column that is rawdata(:,1) against the english word 
%%// and returns a binary array with 1s where the match is found
match = ismember(rawdata(:,1),english_word); 

%%// Use the binary array from above to use only the matching row and
%%// return the second column of it, which is our much needed marathi word 
marathi_word = char(rawdata(match,2))
```

**Note:** Using the second output argument from `xlsread` would work too.

Comment: Please explain this code. i m not getting anything as i m new to matlab.

Comment: @user3498372 Added extensive comments to help you understand. Hope this clarifies most of it.

Comment: @user3498372 Considering accepting the answer that has satisfied the needs of your question(s). Read more about accepting answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer